# @html.validationmessagefor does n't show error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following viewmodel in my mvc project.

```
public class AddGISViewModel
{
    public myproject.Models.DomainModels.GIS gis { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<myproject.Models.DomainModels.Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a view as this

```
@model myproject.ViewModels.GIS.AddGISViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "GIS", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", Url = "/GIS/Create" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("company", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name"), "select company please ", htmlAttributes: new  {@class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

also I have created following metadata

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "you should select company")]
    [DisplayName("company")]
    [Display(Name = "company")]
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }
```

When I run my project @validationmessagefor show 'CompanyID is a required field' not 'you should select company' that I define in metadata. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Apply those attributes to the `AddGISViewModel` class

Comment: thank you so much, I apply thos attributes to the addGISViewModel and that is worked. Is there any way instead of this way?

Comment: Why would you not want to do it the right way? (you have created a view model which should represent exactly what you need in the view, including display and validation attributes)

Comment: I want to do it. I ask about other ways because I want to learn different ways if there are.Thank you for your help. :-)

Comment: You can also add validation messages the the ModelState in the controller like this: `ModelState.AdModelError("propertyName", "some error message");` `propertyName` should match the property of the form to be highlighted, e.g. `"CompanyID"`. Use this if you have to show error messages generated by the backend. For validation messages of the frontend, annotate the ViewModel as suggested by Stephen. Or implement `IValidatableObject` on the ViewModel if you need custom validation logic.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please post your answer to make it selected as true answer.

Comment: Sorry. My Internet connection was cut off. I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a view model, so apply those attributes to the property in the view model. Since the purpose of a view model is to represent what you want to display/edit in the view there is no point creating a separate class for metadata.

Your view model should be

```
public class AddGISViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "you should select company")]
    [DisplayName("company")]
    public long? CompanyID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Note that the `CompanyID` property should be nullable to protect against under-posting attacks, and the collection property for displaying the companies n the dropdownlist should be IEnumerable, so that the view is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID, Model.Companies, "select company please ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In addition, view models should not contain data models if your editing any properties of that model. If so replace `GIS gis` with each property of `GIS` that you need in the view.